# Excel Matrix get (multiple) values

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, excel-formula

As you can see we've got a matrix with data in it. (I removed the header of rows and columns, since it's corporate information that isn't supposed to be spread around.)

Link: http://i49.tinypic.com/5jwayg.jpg

This is what I need:

- When there is a 'X' in the matrix, I need the value of the column where it's placed underneath (from the 'yellow' range: B1:W1). As you can see, it's possible to have more 'X' in one row ('blue' range: A3:A48)
- So when A11 is selected, I need the values of B11 and M11)

I hope somebody is able to achieve this with just functions?

Comment: It is not possible to return multiple matches to a single cell without using VBA / user-defined function. There is [an example](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/12/20/excel-udf-lookup-and-return-multiple-values-concatenated-into-one-cell/) of such a UDF, but you may have to make some modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA Solution.

If I understand your issue correctly, this should work, or at least be a great start.

```
Option Explicit

Function findvalues(rng As Range) As String

Dim cel As Range, str As String

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = "X" Then str = str & "," & cel.Value
Next

findvalues = Mid(str, 2)

End Function
```

Implement it like so, given your spreadsheet in the link

In cell A3 `=findvalues(B3:W3)` In cell B2 `=findvalues(B3:B48)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would get the value of both B11 and M11, but you can do this cell by cell.  Just do this:

```
=IF(A1 = "X", COLUMN(A1), "")
```

That will get you the column number of A1 aka '1'.  There's bound to be a way to get what you desire with VBA, but I'm not very experienced with that just yet and so I would be of little assistance to you.